# Can I default all pytest runs under pycharm to use the `--tb=native` flag?

Tags: pycharm, pytest

When I run a unittest from pycharm the traceback is, in my opinion, hideous. Adding `--tb=native` to `Run/Debug Configurations` / `Additional Arguments` will output native tracebacks and make things easier to read.

When I run a unittest from the pycharm UI it will create a default Python tests run configuration for me, but every time it does I have to go into the run configuration and add `--tb=native`, which is tedious.

Is there a way to add this pytest attribute by default to all run configurations that get created automatically by pycharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer just after posting the question. Under `Run Configurations` there's a `Templates` section, then `Python tests` for the unittest templates. If you add the additional aguments there they will always show up by default.

Comment: I was looking for a way to add the --basetemp flag, works the same way (putting this here so that google might help future me).  For anyone like me struggling to find this button, it's under Run -> Edit Configurations and then blue link in bottom left corner "Edit configuration templates..."